# Parse HTML into web service from Classic ASP

Tags: c#, .net, asp-classic

I am trying to build a webservice where a user enters HTML and then via a web service verifies if it is valid HTML.

My example (basic only) is:

```
Set objXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")         
Dim strEnvelope 
strEnvelope = "input=" & Server.HTMLEncode("<b>") 
Call objXML.Open("POST", "http://[DOMAIN]/WebServices/HTMLWebService.asmx/ValidateHTML", false) 
Call objXML.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded") 
Call objXML.Send(strEnvelope) 

Response.Write(strEnvelope & "##" & objXML.responseText & "##")
```

My ASPX page validates the input and then returns if it's true of false (in a string array XML). At the moment it's always returning false.
After some investigation it seems that for some reason the input received by the ASMX is empty and it's to do with the HTML tagging - either it's not being HTML encoded or not accepted by the asmx script.  It's returning the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<string />
<string>false</string>
</ArrayOfString>
```

<string /> is where I am putting the input directly back into the returned xml string array. If I hard code "<b>" into this value, the xml returns this as "<b>" which is what I'd expect.

If I just put an input of "b" then it returns false but does give me a value of "b" in the first item of the string array - so it's definitely picking up that value.

Has anyone ever parsed html into an ASP.NET (c#) web service before or have any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like your issue is with the web service. If that's what you need debugged, then you need to show us the code from the web service.

Comment: Can you post the server side code?

Comment: I've trimmed this down a bit to get rid of any junk, but here is my web service code....just the routine:

    `public string[] HTMLValidate(string input)
    {
 //HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("##" + input + "##");
 //HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

        string[] returnedvalues = new string[2];

 input = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(input);

 returnedvalues[0] = input;
        returnedvalues[1] = IsvalidHTML(input);
        return returnedvalues;        

    }`

Comment: Consider what validating HTML means.  There are *many* sites which has malformed HTML, but browsers still render them ok.  Validating HTML doesn't get you much, given that most HTML is able to be rendered (even if poorly).

Comment: Further testing provides me with the information that it's not the html that has the problem, it seems to be any ampersand (so any HTMLencoded characters). How can these be handled in a web service via classic ASP?

Comment: I think I have answered my own question - it works, but is it the best solution? 
`Input = "<b>"` 
`Input = Server.HTMLEncode(Input) `
`Input = Server.URLEncode(Input)`

Then do the reverse in the webservice code:
    `input = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(input);`
    `input = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(input);`

 
























add comment

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but since you specify in your request header that the contenttype is  ***"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"*** it could be that you need to use URLEncode and not HTMLEncode. 
Thus, try using:

```
strEnvelope = "input=" & Server.URLEncode("<b>")
```